# get all second highest values from a mysql table

Tags: mysql

I have a table with two fields as follows,

```
name    score
xyz      300
pqr      200
abc      300
mno      100
erp      200
yut      200
```

How can I retrieve all second highest score from above table using MySQL query. Tried as follows,

```
SELECT name, MAX( `score` )
FROM score
WHERE score < (
SELECT MAX( score )
FROM score )
```

but it returns single value.

Expected result ,

```
name    score
pqr      200
erp      200
yut      200
```

Any help please

Comment: What is "second highest"? If there are `3 3 3 3 3 2 2 2 1 1 1 1` - what are the second highest here?

Comment: whats your expected output for the above data?

Comment: "Expected result" -- what if there were multiple `300` values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
SELECT 
  `name`,
  `score`
FROM 
  `score`
WHERE 
  `score`=(SELECT DISTINCT `score` FROM `score` ORDER BY `score` DESC LIMIT 1,1)
```

Tip: naming table and it's column with same names will cause troubles in complicated queries (for you, not for DBMS)

Comment: shouldn't the limit be 1,1?

Comment: @zerkms - I think second highest **valuES** means that it should be `3 3` for `3 3 1`

Comment: Hehe, added `DISTINCT` after me

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo, your query will return all highest values. But I need all second highest values.

Comment: @zerkms actually, I'm making edits and did that after you've posted `3 3 1` sample - so thanks to you I've found my oversight. If it was after (may be few seconds) you've posted your answer - well, I guess I should have very good connection to do that :p

Comment: @mystack well, it will return all values will `score` equal to second score value in table. Is it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Created a sample here on sqlfiddle and it shows as per your excepted output.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ce7a1/1

```
SELECT name, score
FROM score
WHERE score = (SELECT MAX(score) FROM score WHERE score < (SELECT MAX(score) FROM score))
```

Comment: This doesn't scale at all. How would this solution scale when we need the third highest value? What about the 4th highest value? And the nth highest?

Answer (score 0):

If second highest score and comma separated list of names of that second highest score is fine, it can be done using single query like below

```
SELECT group_concat(name) as names,`score` FROM `score` group by `score` 
ORDER BY `score` DESC LIMIT 1,1
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple query

```
SELECT name, score 
FROM score 
WHERE score=(SELECT DISTINCT score FROM score ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 1,1)
```